# .NET: Non-generic for KeyValuePair<string, string>?

Tags: c#, .net

I could've sworn that before `System.Collections.Generic`, there was a class that was effectively `KeyValuePair<string, string`>.

In other words, it was an object with one two members: a name or key, and value, and both were typed as strings.

Anyone know what I'm referring to?

Answer (score 5):

Its properties are objects (not strings), but maybe you're looking for [DictionaryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry.aspx) because it's the object type returned when you iterate a [StringDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringdictionary.aspx).

Comment: DictionaryEntry uses `object` for its `Key` and `Value`. The question specifically asks about properties typed as `String`.

Comment: Bradley, Hans: You're right, its members are objects, but it's what you get out of a `StringDictionary` so it may be what the OP was thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

The class you are looking for is the StringDictionary.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringdictionary.aspx